# Apache reverse proxy authentication via PHP

Tags: php, apache, authentication, reverse-proxy

I have two apache servers set up.  One is public facing, the other is behind a firewall.  The one behind the firewall is used to serve up content (vids, pics, etc).  I've set up a reverse proxy so that any requests to http://mysite.com/content/ actually go to the server inside my firewall.  See my serverfault [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/78778/symbolic-link-network-volume).

My site uses PHP and MySQL to authenticate users. The authentication doesn't work on anything in the /content directory because apache immediately sends the request to the internal server.  Ideally I'd like to authenticate users on my public facing server, and give them content from the content server inside the firewall.

Is there a way to only allow authenticated users access to the /content directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>While this answer may not represent a "best practice", it does work nicely</sup>

We use a back-end server with apache as a "fileserver" of sorts -- to serve private files and images that users upload to their account.  Here is how it works:

Setup mod_rewrite to handle the URLs however you wish.  For example:

```
RewriteRule /content/(.*)   /ServeContent.php?FileName=$1
```

The script ServeContent.php will do the following:

```
1. Validate input

2. Authenticate user based on cookie or session data

3. Make a URL with $_GET['FileName'] and the IP of the backend server
   http://192.168.1.30/content/somefile.jpg

4. Set appropriate headers for the file type
   header('Content-type: image/jpeg')

5. readfile($URL)
```

This approach requires that fopen-wrappers are enabled in PHP.  `readfile` will not store the content in memory, so this really does not use much memory.  One of the main disadvantages is that you will hold up an apache/php process for the duration of the request (which could be a long time).  But realistically, you probabally will not have a problem unless you are running a high-traffic site.

If you are, there are most likely better solutions out there.  But this has worked very effectively for us for large files on a variety of applications.

Comment: sigh, I wish that would work.  Some of the "content" on my content server is folders of HTML pages with relative links to other pages and images.

Comment: Are you sure there is a problem?  Can't you just detect or determine the right content type when sending the file back?

Comment: Looking at your answer again, it looks like that would work.  Is there any advantage this approach has over using .htaccess and a cookie? http://www.willmaster.com/blog/contentprotection/htaccess-cookie.php

Comment: With the cookie method mentioned, you are relying on a shared secret.  Once anyone has the cookie name, they have access.  With the above approach, you can finely control who has access to what.  It's really up to you -- do you want it *secure* or just *obscure* ?